# sum of corresponding column of a consecutive duplicate elements in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, typeerror

I am trying to find the sum of the corresponding column of duplicate elements in the data frame.
here :

```
import pandas as pd

a=[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,0,1,1]
b=[5,4,3,9,8,7,5,4,3,10,8]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns =['Patch', 'Reward']) 

df = df.groupby((df.Patch != df.Patch.shift(1)).cumsum())
df['Reward_sum']=df.Reward.sum()

print(df)
```

throws an error :

```
TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment
```

however, I wanted the output to look like this:
where Reward_sum = sum of reward corresponding to consecutive duplicate patch and Reward avg = sum of reward/number of times a duplicate patch appears consecutively.

```
Patch     Reward_sum    Reward avg
0         12             4
1         17             8.5
2         12             6
0         7              3.5
1         18             9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there!

```
(df.groupby((df.Patch != df.Patch.shift(1)).cumsum(), as_index=False)
   .agg(Patch=("Patch", "first"), 
        Reward_sum=("Reward", "sum"), 
        Reward_avg=("Reward", "mean"))
)
```